# SWFUpload and SSL Client Certificate upload

Tags: ssl, swfupload

I am using **swfUpload** (Flash control) to upload files to the web site.

This is working great except when the web site uses SSL with **client certificate** for authentication.

In IE there is no problem, but with Chrome and Firefox the upload fails.

The upload then fails because the POST request with the file data (coming from swfUpload) is rejected because the client certificate is not provided with the post.

I guess this is a Flash Plugin problem since it is working correctly in IE using the same swfUpload.swf...

Anyone familiar with this problem and is there a fix?

Comment: Found this in my searches. Still have this issue? I have a similar situation where I have a site under SSL (that's under a different name - server vs domain) and I get the I/O error when trying to upload in Chrome/FF.